# How to fetch the all data based on a particular date?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I am using SQLite to store my information. **I am storing the date as string format. Now I want to fetch the data based on the date, there might be more than one data for a single date. I have checked relevant questions and tried in my way but can not find the solution. Though I was able to get info of a single data for a particular date.**

**My code for fetching data from the database:**

```
public ArrayList<ExpenseModel> getSingleExpenseDetails(String date){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from " + TABLE_SAVE_EXPENSE + " where "+ COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE+ " = '" + date+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    ExpenseModel expenseModel=new ExpenseModel();
    ArrayList<ExpenseModel> expenseModels = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.v("Title : ",""+title);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            expenseModel.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_TITLE)));
            expenseModel.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION)));
            expenseModel.setAmount(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_AMOUNT)));
            expenseModel.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE)));
            expenseModel.setCurrency(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_CURRENCY)));
            Log.v("Info : ",""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_TITLE)));
            expenseModels.add(expenseModel)
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return expenseModels;
}
```

**ExpenseModel class:**

```
package app.shakil.com.dailyexpense.Models;

public class ExpenseModel {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String date;
    private int amount;
    private String currency;

public ExpenseModel(){

}

public ExpenseModel(String title,String description,String date,int amount,String currency){
    this.title=title;
    this.description=description;
    this.date=date;
    this.amount=amount;
    this.currency=currency;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(String currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code should be working if `date` is in the format of the column `COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE`.

Comment: The format is the same but the problem occurs when there are multiple data for a single date.

Comment: What problem? You will get all the rows for that date.

Comment: It can not find all the data for that specified date and it returns an empty ExpenseModel.

Comment: Then you don't pass the proper date value or format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious mistake that you do in your code is that you initialize `expenseModel` before the loop and use it inside the loop for all the rows:

```
ExpenseModel expenseModel=new ExpenseModel();
```

Move that line inside the loop:

```
do {
    ExpenseModel expenseModel=new ExpenseModel();   
    expenseModel.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_TITLE)));
    expenseModel.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_DESCRIPTION)));
    expenseModel.setAmount(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_AMOUNT)));
    expenseModel.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_DATE)));
    expenseModel.setCurrency(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_CURRENCY)));
    Log.v("Info : ",""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPENSE_TITLE)));
    expenseModels.add(expenseModel)
}while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Thanks this solves my problem. But I never think of it this way.